# Como trazer em Razor um DropDown com o elemento já selecionado partir de uma base de dados?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Eu criei uma cadastro onde um objeto tem n elementos e cada um deles é selecionado a partir de um DropDown, o cadastro funciona perfeitamente porém quando vou editar os DropDowns não mostram  o item selecionado de acordo com o que foi salvo no Banco:

Segue o código da view:

```
                        for (var i = 0; i < Model.vehicletanks.Count; i++)
                        {
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.vehicletanks[i].fueltype, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.FuelTypeSelectList, Resources.Select, new { @class = "form-control" })

                        }
```

Se eu trocar o "DropDownListFor" por um "EditorFor" ele traz o valor corretamente, "fueltype" é um inteiro de 0 a 14.

Answer (score 0):

Yuri, tente retornar na sua ViewBag um SelectList.
Não sei se entendi direito, mas você está montando na tela uma sequencia de DropDownList.
Creio que o valor que vc está trazendo na ViewBag não seja o correspondente.

> View:
>
> @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UsuarioId,
>                        (SelectList)ViewBag.ListaUsuario,
>                        "-- Selecione",
>                        new { @class = "form-control" })
>
> Controller:
>
> ViewBag.ListaUsuario = new SelectList(usuarioRegra.ObterTodos(), "Id",
>   "Login", UsuarioPermissao.UsuarioId);

Sendo que  **usuarioRegra.ObterTodos()** retorna
**IEnumerable**